# как можно изменить эту классовую функцию на функцию с хуками? на что можно изменить эти static?

Tags: reactjs

**Вот это мой файл для валидации формы **

```
const regex = {
    email: new RegExp(
        '^(([^<>()\\[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@]+(\\.[^<>()\\[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@]+)*)|(.+))@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$',
    ),
    number: new RegExp('^[0-9]+$'),
};

export class Validators {
    static email(value, message) {
        if (value) {
            const result = regex.email.test(value);
            if (!result) return { error: true, message };
        }
        return false;
    }

    static required(value, message) {
        if (!value || !value.toString().trim().length) {
            return { error: true, message };
        }
         return false;
    }

    static number(value, message) {
        const length = value ? value.toString().length : 0;

        if (length > 0) {
            const result = regex.number.test(value);
            if (!result) {
                return { error: true, message };
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

   
}

export const validateInput = (validators, value) => {
    if (validators && validators.length) {
        for (let i = 0; i < validators.length; i++) {
            const error = validators[i].check(value, validators[i].message);
            if (error) {
                return error;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему бы просто не вынести это в отдельные функции?

```
const regex = {
  email: new RegExp(
    '^(([^<>()\\[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@]+(\\.[^<>()\\[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@]+)*)|(.+))@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$',
  ),
  number: new RegExp('^[0-9]+$'),
};

function validateEmail(value, message) {
  if (value) {
    const result = regex.email.test(value);
    if (!result) return { error: true, message };
  }
  return false;
}

function validateNumber(value, message) {
  const length = value ? value.toString().length : 0;

  if (length > 0) {
    const result = regex.number.test(value);
    if (!result) {
      return { error: true, message };
    }
  }

  return false;
}

export { validateEmail, validateNumber }
```

---

**UPD**

а если так хочется через хук это делать, то можно создать папку hooks, и создать хук:

```
export function useValidator(type, value) {
  switch (type) {
    case "email":
      return validateEmail(value)
    case "number":
      return validateNumber(value)
    // etc
  }
}
```